# Date and Time Settings on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a dual boot with `Windows 7` and I have noticed that intermittently, `Windows 7` cannot remember the time I am in and is constantly hours ahead (no matter how often I change it to the correct time). Does anyone recommend something other than simply changing the time settings in the `Control Panel` that will keep the time so that I don't have to constantly change it?

Comment: "I have a dual boot with Windows 7". What is the other operating system that's on your machine?

Comment: Ubuntu, but why would that matter? The issue is only occurring when I boot into Windows.

Comment: It makes a difference. See my answer as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu stores time as UTC, while Windows uses "local" time.  As a result, both operating systems are using the same hardware clock, but interpreting it differently (causing the time discrepancies). You should switch Ubuntu to use local time instead of UTC time, thus keeping the two operating system's times in sync. You can do this by editing `/etc/default/rcS` and changing `UTC=yes` to `UTC=no`.

You can change Windows to run on UTC time, however there is speculation that this causes additional issues. The link below has the solution to convert Windows to UTC, however I have not included it in my answer.

*Source:* https://askubuntu.com/questions/375492/dual-boot-win-7-ubuntu-13-10-clock-problem

*Link to Ubuntu's Help Center Topic*: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts

Comment: I'll give it a shot

Comment: Just edited the conf file. I will keep you posted.